# Issue in MySQL stored procedure from 5.0 to 5.1

Tags: mysql

When I upgraded from MySQL 5.0 to 5.1, the following SQL statement in an SP stopped working with error code 1064 - invalid column name VARCLNO in WHERE clause:

```
SELECT *, CLNO as VARCLNO, concat(CLCompany, CLSurname, CLFirstName, CLNO) as CLSort FROM Customer WHERE
 CLEditDate = (select max(CLEditDate) from Customer WHERE VARCLNO = CLNO )
 ORDER BY CLSort;
```

The CUSTOMER table columns all begin CL.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query using table alias:

```
SELECT *, 
      CLNO as VARCLNO, 
      concat(CLCompany, CLSurname, CLFirstName, CLNO) as CLSort 
FROM Customer AS T1 
      WHERE
         CLEditDate = (select max(CLEditDate) from Customer WHERE T1.CLNO = CLNO )
ORDER BY CLSort;
```

Comment: That has fixed the issue, thank you. Any reason why the original code would work under 5.0 and not under 5.1?

Comment: @user2236230: You use VARCLNO in a subquery but it is alias of field CLNO from the main select list. I think it is the issue.